# Google+ iOS API Wrapper

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-plus

Was wondering if anybody has found or made a iOS wrapper for the Google+ API yet?

Been searching the web and so far have not found anything at all for this yet.

Maybe too new?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the google+ API [here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) and an alpha version of their library [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/).

Answer (score 0):

The recently announced Google+ iOS SDK and sample app demonstrate how you can integrate the share plugin, sign-in button, and use the Google+ history API.

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/